# Blender Game Engine dynamic text wordwrap

Tags: game-engine, text-object

I want to display some text that change dynamically when I select another item. Displaying the text is working, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make the text multilines and/or wordwraping it so the text don't shows on only one line.

I saw some explainations on the web but these informations are over 8 years old.

It can be done by adding some "\n" in the string, but i would like to do it automatically like any textbox in most of UIs.

Can you guys help me on that issue please?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it by using the Python standard library's [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module. I've written [this](https://www.facebook.com/notes/bgempire/bge-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-texto/971421119704334/) article about text alignement in BGE some time ago, you may find it useful (it's in brazilian portuguese, you may try to use Google Translate on it). Here I will explain about left alignement, but in the article I explain about center and right alignement as well. Example file with all the modes provided below.

## Left aligned text

With this simple setup:

[image]

The following code:

```py
import bge
import textwrap

def main(cont):

    # Objects
    own = cont.owner

    # Sensors
    sensor = cont.sensors[0]

    # Properties
    text = 'The Blender Game Engine is a component of Blender, a free and open-source 3D production suite, used for making real-time interactive content. The game engine was written from scratch in C++ as a mostly independent component, and includes support for features such as Python scripting and OpenAL 3D sound.'

    #### INITIALIZE ####
    if sensor.positive:

        # Max number line characters before line breaks
        line_size = 35

        # Left alignement
        own.text = textwrap.fill(text, line_size)
```

It results in:

[image]

## Example file

[image]